# NSObject subclass custom method causing NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: objective-c, nsobject, subclassing

I'm using `NSJSONSerialization` to grab some JSON and parse it into a custom `NSObject` subclass. That works just fine, and I can retrieve values out of it using:

```
CustomProperties* properties = [[CustomProperties alloc] init];
[properties objectForKey:@"nameOfKey"]
```

Simple implementation for my subclass:

**CustomProperties.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CustomProperties : NSObject

- (id)objectForKey:(NSString *)key;

@end
```

**CustomProperties.m**

```
@implementation CustomProperties

-(id) init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        /* do most of initialization */
    }
    return(self);
}

- (id)objectForKey:(NSString *)key
{
    return nil;
}

@end
```

**The problem**

I'm trying to add a custom instance method that can process the retrieved value into a float using a default value if the retrieved JSON value is nil.

My thought was something simple like:

**CustomProperties.h**

```
@interface CustomProperties : NSObject

// ...existing id interface here
- (CGFloat)getFloatValueForKey:(NSString*)key defaultValue:(CGFloat)defaultValue;

@end
```

**CustomProperties.m**

```
@implementation CustomProperties

// ...existing id method here

- (CGFloat)getFloatValueForKey:(NSString*)key defaultValue:(CGFloat)defaultValue
{
    if (key == nil)
        return 0;

    if ([self objectForKey:key] == nil)
        return defaultValue;
    else
        return [[self objectForKey:key] floatValue];
}

@end
```

So that I can then call it like:

```
CustomProperties* properties = [[CustomProperties alloc] init];
[properties getFloatValueForKey:@"nameOfKey" defaultValue:0.2];
```

This of course causes a whopping:

```
-[__NSCFDictionary getFloatValueForKey:defaultValue:]: 
unrecognized selector sent to instance
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary getFloatValueForKey:defaultValue:]: 
unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I truly understand that it's not implemented properly and that I'm missing something! Just don't know what.

**Edit**

Digging deeper, it appears that when it's first being initialized (when I'm parsing the JSON) it's setting it to type `__NSCFDictionary`:

```
CustomProperties* properties = [[CustomProperties alloc] init];
properties = [jsonNSDictionaryObjectInstance objectForKey:@"properties"];
customDetailsInstance.properties = properties;
```

Comment: First of all, "instance" is not an instance of CustomProperties. If you want to parse your JSON dictionary using getFloatValueForKey:default: you should create it as a category of dictionary.

Comment: Poor choice of words. Edited. Don't really want to use dictionary, since I'm going to have a set list of defined properties - some floats, some strings, some comma separated values.

Comment: I see a default / defaultValue mismatch in the selector name...  also, "get" is generally omitted in method names, so clearly the gods are smiting thee.

Comment: @stevesliva syntax typo in my copying the code to the question. Edited. Changing it to remove `get` also had no effect.

Comment: lol.  You're subclassing NSObject and not NSDictionary?  I can't see why the __NSCFDictionary class is being sent your message here...  even so, you could try returning instancetype or CustomProperties* from the init method

Comment: @stevesliva That's what I guessed from the log.

Comment: @remus You don't get crash if you run the code you posted. I copied and tried your code. It was fine. Hope you see you will always get default value you passed if you run that instant methods.

Comment: @HMHero what it's doing isn't important; I'm digging into the way I'm initializing it to see why it's throwing the NSDictionary error.

Comment: instancetype is implied in an init method... but something's screwy.

Comment: I've actually created a @property of this class on *another* subclass of NSObject, in a hierarchy. But something is _definitely_ off somewhere higher up. I just assumed it was this code causing the problem.

Comment: Getting somewhere: when I'm first initializing the CustomProperties instances, they're coming up as __NSCFDictionary. Going to figure out why that is.. I suspect I need to change the way I'm initializing it.

Comment: AH HA! I had to create a custom initWithProperties method that captured the incoming NSCFDictionary and parse the properties using objectForKey. Thanks for the help guys!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create a custom `initWithProperties` method that captured the incoming NSCFDictionary and parse the properties using `objectForKey`.

When parsing the JSON:

```
// jsonNSDictionaryObjectInstance is actually an __NSCFDictionary
CustomProperties* properties = [[CustomProperties alloc] initinitWithProperties[initWithProperties objectForKey@"theJSONKeyYouAreParsing"]];
customDetailsInstance.properties = properties;
```

And then for the CustomProperties class:

**.h**

```
- (id)initWithProperties:(NSDictionary*)properties;

@property (nonatomic) CGFloat aCustomProperty;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat anotherCustomProperty;
```

**.m**

```
-(id) initWithProperties:(NSDictionary*)properties
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        /* do most of initialization */
        self.aCustomProperty = [[properties objectForKey:@"jsonSubKey"] floatValue];
        self.anotherCustomProperty = [[properties objectForKey:@"anotherJsonSubkey"] floatValue];
    }
    return(self);
}
```

Comment: You should change your question too.